# Criteria that filters by subclass of filed declared by super class in domain class

Tags: grails, inheritance, criteria

i have the following domain class

```
class Session{

   static hasMany=[lessons:Lesson]
}

class BasicSession extends Session{

    }
class AdvancedSession extends Session{

}
```

know that Lesson is also a domain class:

```
class Lesson {
   static belongsTo=[session:Session]
}
```

What's the Criteria that retrieves all lessons that belongs to Session `subclass` (`BasicSession` or `AdvancedSession`)

if i want to explain what i mean , i can write :

```
// lessons belong only to AdvancedSession 

    Lesson.createCriteria().list{
           session{
               eq('class','slm.abdennour.AdvancedSession') // !!!
            }       

    }
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is the way to go: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-Criteria-Querying-associations-filter-on-concrete-Class-td1368250.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After consulting  [this Issue](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-Criteria-Querying-associations-filter-on-concrete-Class-td1368250.html), the solution is as what i said in question but , instead of `String` type , use `Class` type .

That it means :

```
eq('class',slm.abdennour.AdvancedSession)
```

and not

```
eq('class','slm.abdennour.AdvancedSession')
```